# Заполнить пропущенные данные (NaN) в Pandas Series из другой Series по такому же индексу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame df1 и df2, а точнее Series. Их содержимое приведено на рисунке. Необходимо  строки df1, которые имеют значение NaN, заполнить значениями аналогичных по индексу строк из df2. То есть в df1 значение последней строки (выделена зеленым цветом) должно быть Fatima. 
      Мне удалось сделать решение через цикл и функцию iloc. Но интуитивно понимаю, что это не правильно. Может можно сделать как-то поизящней, без такого цикла. 
Заранее благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
NullPos = pnd.isnull(df1)
k=0
for indx in NullPos:
    if   indx == True:
    df2.iloc[k]=df1.iloc[k]
    print (df2.iloc[k],k)
    k=k+1
```

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!

Comment: если ответ вам помог, вы можете [принять лучший, по вашему мнению, ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) и [проголосовать за все понравившиеся ответы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

Demo:

```
In [117]: s1 = pd.Series(list('abcdefg'))

In [118]: s1.loc[::2] = pd.np.nan

In [119]: s2 = pd.Series(list('ABCDEFZ'))

In [120]: s1
Out[120]:
0    NaN
1      b
2    NaN
3      d
4    NaN
5      f
6    NaN
dtype: object

In [121]: s2
Out[121]:
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
6    Z
dtype: object
```

Решение:

```
In [122]: s1 = s1.combine_first(s2)

In [123]: s1
Out[123]:
0    A
1    b
2    C
3    d
4    E
5    f
6    Z
dtype: object
```